# JSON file (Extracting data)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following data in a JSON file (pio2.json)

```
{
"controles":[{
        "chart":[{
            "type":"columns",
            "title":"Pollitos"
        }],
        "datos":[{"key":"Math","value":98},
                 {"key":"Physics","value":78},
                 {"key":"Biology","value":70},
                 {"key":"Chemistry","value":90},
                 {"key":"Literature","value":79}
                ]
        }]
}
```

I need to extract data in array for a chart from "datos" for my html / javascript

```
$(function () {
    var processed_json = new Array(); 
    $.getJSON('pio2.json', function(data)
    {
        // Populate series
        for (i = 0; i < data.controles.length; i++){
            processed_json.push(data.controles[i].chart);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: what is your end format requirement?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of the *advice* you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info!! I need to return in a variable from chart "type" and in an array from datos "key" and "value"

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your issue is. I should be serialized server side and deserialized client side. When deserialized, it will be in an array.

Comment: Maybe I can be wrong but your 'json' seems to be invalid :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied your data, as is, into json1.json pasted in your code and made some minor changes and it worked fine. I got the results out of the json page into my html page.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var processed_json = new Array(); 
             $.getJSON('json1.json', function(data)
             {
                 // Populate series
                 for (i = 0; i < data.controles.length; i++){
                     processed_json.push(data.controles[i].chart);
                 }
             })
         });  
    </script>
</body>
```